# Adding an extra field for Zizaco/confide keeps resulting in error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Hello I am using Laravel ( new to this framework ) and the Zizaco/Confide package. I have managed to edit a lot with my own needs en preferences but I can't seem to solve this one problem about adding a new input field to create new users as admin

> see form.day_of_birth field

[image]

The error says that the field is not filled altho it is ( I have checked with printing the array of sessions after submit on my screen )

In the AdminUserController I have changed the PostEdit() method and the PostCreate() method adding the following

```
public function postCreate()
{
    $this->user->username = Input::get( 'username' );
    $this->user->email = Input::get( 'email' );
    $this->user->birthday = Input::get( 'd__day_of_birth__m' );
    $this->user->password = Input::get( 'password' );

    // The password confirmation will be removed from model
    // before saving. This field will be used in Ardent's
    // auto validation.
    $this->user->password_confirmation = Input::get( 'password_confirmation' );
    $this->user->confirmed = Input::get( 'confirm' );

    // Permissions are currently tied to roles. Can't do this yet.
    //$user->permissions = $user->roles()->preparePermissionsForSave(Input::get( 'permissions' ));

    // Save if valid. Password field will be hashed before save
    $this->user->save();

    if ( $this->user->id )
    {
        // Save roles. Handles updating.
        $this->user->saveRoles(Input::get( 'roles' ));

        // Redirect to the new user page
        return Redirect::to('admin/users/' . $this->user->id . '/edit')->with('success', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.create.success'));
    }
    else
    {
        // Get validation errors (see Ardent package)
        $error = $this->user->errors()->all();

        return Redirect::to('admin/users/create')
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
            ->with( 'error', $error );
    }
}
```

I have practically the same on the sign up page for the users to create a own account and that works like a charm. Somehow here it doesn't seem to work..

In the view I have added this

```
                 <div class="form-group {{{ $errors->has('d__day_of_birth__m') ? 'error' : '' }}}">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="day_of_birth">{{{ Lang::get('form.day_of_birth') }}}</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="form-control js__birthdaypicker" placeholder="{{{ Lang::get('form.day_of_birth') }}}" type="text" name="day_of_birth" id="day_of_birth" value="{{{ Input::old('day_of_birth', isset($user) ? $user->email : null) }}}"/>
                    {{{ $errors->first('d__day_of_birth__m', '<span class="help-inline">:message</span>') }}}
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the html you named the input `day_of_birth` not `d__day_of_birth__m`.

Comment: Yes, That is because the date picker I use provides 2 kind of submitted dates. One is a human friendly version ( day_of_birth ) and the other one is the one I work with ( 2013-12-27 example)